# Jetpack Compose: DropdownMenu appears in the wrong position

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have made a DropDownMenu-Element with Jetpack Compose. It works, but I'm not able to control the position in which in appears. Precise: It appears much too far below. I would expect it right below the icon or above the icon.

[image: Screenshot]

My Source-Code:

```
var expanded by remember {
    mutableStateOf(false)
}
var shift by remember {
    mutableStateOf("0")
}
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top) {
    IconButton(onClick = {expanded = !expanded }) {
        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.AccountBox,
            contentDescription = "")
    }
    DropdownMenu(expanded = expanded, 
        onDismissRequest = { expanded = !expanded },
        modifier = Modifier) {
        for (i in 1..7) {
            DropdownMenuItem(
                text = { Text(text = "$i") },
                onClick = {
                    shift = i.toString()
                    expanded = !expanded
                })
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried various settings, but nothing worked. It stays the way it is shown.

**What I'm doing wrong? Have can I make it behave as expected?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are filling the max height in the column, by using fillMaxHeight modifier, you are telling compose to use all the height available in the screen.

this should work:

```
   var expanded by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    var shift by remember {
        mutableStateOf("0")
    }
    Column{
        IconButton(onClick = { expanded = !expanded }) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Filled.AccountBox,
                contentDescription = ""
            )
        }
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = !expanded },
            modifier = Modifier
        ) {
            for (i in 1..7) {
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    text = { Text(text = "$i") },
                    onClick = {
                        shift = i.toString()
                        expanded = !expanded
                    })
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had to remove the Modifier.fillMaxSize() on the parent as well. Together with your code it works now as expected. Thanks a lot.